# MultiBroker Kafka on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm fairly new to kubernetes and trying to deploy a 2-broker kafka. after applying the configuration I see two brokers (kafka-0 and kafka-1) are trying to run but both throw following exceptions. I'm fairly new to kubernetes so not really able to diagnose the actual problem here.

first exception

```
[2022-02-21 13:31:34,172] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 3 started leader election for partition [__consumer_offsets,41] (state.change.logger)
[2022-02-21 13:31:34,182] DEBUG [OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector]: No broker in ISR is alive for [__consumer_offsets,41]. Pick the leader from the alive assigned replicas:  (kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector)
[2022-02-21 13:31:34,182] ERROR Controller 0 epoch 3 initiated state change for partition [__consumer_offsets,41] from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition failed (state.change.logger)
kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica for partition [__consumer_offsets,41] is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], Assigned replicas are: [List(0)]
        at kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader(PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:73)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition(PartitionStateMachine.scala:339)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:200)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:115)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:112)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:112)
        at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.startup(PartitionStateMachine.scala:67)
        at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:342)
        at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:160)
        at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:85)
        at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:51)
        at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49)
        at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:213)
        at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.startup(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49)
        at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:681)
        at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:677)
        at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:677)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:213)
        at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startup(KafkaController.scala:677)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:224)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

second exception

```
java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka-0.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9093 (id: 0 rack: null) failed
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:84)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:94)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:236)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.liftedTree1$1(ControllerChannelManager.scala:189)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:188)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)

java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka-1.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) failed
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:84)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:94)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:236)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.liftedTree1$1(ControllerChannelManager.scala:189)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:188)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
[2022-02-21 13:33:42,421] WARN [Controller-1-to-broker-1-send-thread], Controller 1's connection to broker kafka-1.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
```

following is my complete deloyment.yml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-es-0
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: kafka-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    pod-name: kafka-0
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-es-1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: kafka-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    pod-name: kafka-1
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-hs
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9093
    name: server
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: kafka
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: kafka-pdb
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: demo
spec:
  serviceName: kafka-hs
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - kafka
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        podAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
             - weight: 1
               podAffinityTerm:
                 labelSelector:
                    matchExpressions:
                      - key: "app"
                        operator: In
                        values:
                        - zk
                 topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      initContainers:
      - name: kafka-setup
        image: busybox
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'case $POD_NAME in "kafka-0") echo "service1ip:9092" >> /var/lib/kafka/external ;; "kafka-1") echo "service2ip:9092" >> /var/lib/kafka/external ;; esac']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: "datadir"
          mountPath: "/var/lib/kafka" 
      containers:
      - name: k8skafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-kafka:1.0-10.2.1
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        - containerPort: 9093
          hostPort: 9092
          name: server
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "exec kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties --override broker.id=${HOSTNAME##*-} \
          --override listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT \
          --override advertised.listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://${HOSTNAME}.kafka-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9093,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://$(eval grep . /var/lib/kafka/external | tail -1) \
          --override listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:9093,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:9092 \
          --override inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT \
          --override zookeeper.connect=zoo-service:2181 \
          --override log.dir=/var/lib/kafka \
          --override auto.create.topics.enable=true \
          --override auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true \
          --override background.threads=10 \
          --override compression.type=producer \
          --override delete.topic.enable=false \
          --override leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300 \
          --override leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10 \
          --override log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000 \
          --override log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.retention.bytes=-1 \
          --override log.retention.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.jitter.hours=0 \
          --override log.segment.bytes=1073741824 \
          --override log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000 \
          --override message.max.bytes=1000012 \
          --override min.insync.replicas=1 \
          --override num.io.threads=8 \
          --override num.network.threads=3 \
          --override num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1 \
          --override num.replica.fetchers=1 \
          --override offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096 \
          --override offsets.commit.required.acks=-1 \
          --override offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000 \
          --override offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880 \
          --override offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000 \
          --override offsets.retention.minutes=1440 \
          --override offsets.topic.compression.codec=0 \
          --override offsets.topic.num.partitions=50 \
          --override offsets.topic.replication.factor=3 \
          --override offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600 \
          --override queued.max.requests=500 \
          --override quota.consumer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override quota.producer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override replica.fetch.min.bytes=1 \
          --override replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500 \
          --override replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000 \
          --override replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000 \
          --override replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536 \
          --override replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override request.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override socket.request.max.bytes=104857600 \
          --override socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override unclean.leader.election.enable=true \
          --override zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override zookeeper.set.acl=false \
          --override broker.id.generation.enable=true \
          --override connections.max.idle.ms=600000 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.enable=true \
          --override controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000 \
          --override controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override default.replication.factor=1 \
          --override fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override group.max.session.timeout.ms=300000 \
          --override group.min.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override inter.broker.protocol.version=0.10.2-IV0 \
          --override log.cleaner.backoff.ms=15000 \
          --override log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728 \
          --override log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000 \
          --override log.cleaner.enable=true \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=524288 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=1.7976931348623157E308 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0 \
          --override log.cleaner.threads=1 \
          --override log.cleanup.policy=delete \
          --override log.index.interval.bytes=4096 \
          --override log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime \
          --override log.preallocate=false \
          --override log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 \
          --override max.connections.per.ip=2147483647 \
          --override num.partitions=1 \
          --override producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.backoff.ms=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576 \
          --override replica.fetch.response.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override reserved.broker.max.id=1000 "
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
          value : "-Xmx512M -Xms512M"
        - name: KAFKA_OPTS
          value: "-Dlogging.level=INFO"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /var/lib/kafka
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
           command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --bootstrap-server=localhost:9093"
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

**MADE A FEW CHANGES, NEW .yml BELOW**
kafka-es-0 and kafka-es-1 are now replaced with one service (kafka-service)
and declared as NodePort.
also kafka listener external plaintext is directly exposing service-name:port

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: kafka-service
    visualize: "true"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: kafka-port
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    app: kafka
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-hs
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9093
    name: server
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: kafka
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: kafka-pdb
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: demo
spec:
  serviceName: kafka-hs
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - kafka
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        podAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
             - weight: 1
               podAffinityTerm:
                 labelSelector:
                    matchExpressions:
                      - key: "app"
                        operator: In
                        values:
                        - zk
                 topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      initContainers:
      - name: kafka-setup
        image: busybox
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'case $POD_NAME in "kafka-0") echo "20.108.81.213:9092" >> /var/lib/kafka/external ;; "kafka-1") echo "20.108.81.215:9092" >> /var/lib/kafka/external ;; esac']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: "datadir"
          mountPath: "/var/lib/kafka" 
      containers:
      - name: k8skafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-kafka:1.0-10.2.1
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        - containerPort: 9093
          hostPort: 9092
          name: server
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "exec kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties --override broker.id=${HOSTNAME##*-} \
          --override listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT \
          --override advertised.listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://${HOSTNAME}.kafka-hs.demo.svc.cluster.local:9093,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://kafka-service:9092 \
          --override listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:9093,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:9092 \
          --override inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT \
          --override zookeeper.connect=zoo-service:2181 \
          --override log.dir=/var/lib/kafka \
          --override auto.create.topics.enable=true \
          --override auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true \
          --override background.threads=10 \
          --override compression.type=producer \
          --override delete.topic.enable=false \
          --override leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300 \
          --override leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10 \
          --override log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000 \
          --override log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.retention.bytes=-1 \
          --override log.retention.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.hours=168 \
          --override log.roll.jitter.hours=0 \
          --override log.segment.bytes=1073741824 \
          --override log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000 \
          --override message.max.bytes=1000012 \
          --override min.insync.replicas=2 \
          --override num.io.threads=8 \
          --override num.network.threads=3 \
          --override num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1 \
          --override num.replica.fetchers=1 \
          --override offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096 \
          --override offsets.commit.required.acks=-1 \
          --override offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000 \
          --override offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880 \
          --override offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000 \
          --override offsets.retention.minutes=1440 \
          --override offsets.topic.compression.codec=0 \
          --override offsets.topic.num.partitions=50 \
          --override offsets.topic.replication.factor=2 \
          --override offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600 \
          --override queued.max.requests=500 \
          --override quota.consumer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override quota.producer.default=9223372036854775807 \
          --override replica.fetch.min.bytes=1 \
          --override replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500 \
          --override replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000 \
          --override replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000 \
          --override replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536 \
          --override replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override request.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override socket.request.max.bytes=104857600 \
          --override socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400 \
          --override unclean.leader.election.enable=true \
          --override zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override zookeeper.set.acl=false \
          --override broker.id.generation.enable=true \
          --override connections.max.idle.ms=600000 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.enable=true \
          --override controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3 \
          --override controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000 \
          --override controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000 \
          --override default.replication.factor=1 \
          --override fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override group.max.session.timeout.ms=300000 \
          --override group.min.session.timeout.ms=6000 \
          --override inter.broker.protocol.version=0.10.2-IV0 \
          --override log.cleaner.backoff.ms=15000 \
          --override log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728 \
          --override log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000 \
          --override log.cleaner.enable=true \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=524288 \
          --override log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=1.7976931348623157E308 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5 \
          --override log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0 \
          --override log.cleaner.threads=1 \
          --override log.cleanup.policy=delete \
          --override log.index.interval.bytes=4096 \
          --override log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807 \
          --override log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime \
          --override log.preallocate=false \
          --override log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000 \
          --override max.connections.per.ip=2147483647 \
          --override num.partitions=1 \
          --override producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.backoff.ms=1000 \
          --override replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576 \
          --override replica.fetch.response.max.bytes=10485760 \
          --override reserved.broker.max.id=1000 "
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
          value : "-Xmx512M -Xms512M"
        - name: KAFKA_OPTS
          value: "-Dlogging.level=INFO"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /var/lib/kafka
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
           command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --bootstrap-server=localhost:9093"
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

i am not able to access kafka brokers from outside kubernetes cluster. tried both with using node_hostname:kafka_service_node_port and kubclusterhostname:kafka_service_node_port

Comment: I strongly suggest that you start at https://strimzi.io rather than writing this all on your own with operators or Helm

Comment: https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/configuring.html#assembly-accessing-kafka-outside-cluster-str

Comment: why do you think strimzi is a better option here?

Comment: also there were a few other comments by you yesterday. but I don't see them no more, have you deleted them? they seemed helpful.

Comment: It's "better" than rolling your own because it's self-healing due to being an Operator and it's community maintained, rather than rolling your own. It also provides CRD instances for user ACLs, topics, connectors, etc... In any case, I missed that you actually had three services. However, you definitely do not need one for internal listeners since cluster DNS will always work. For external listeners, I don't really know what the grep command is doing,. You also seem to be be missing `namespace: demo` in the first two services, requiring changing `kafka-hs.default` to `kafka-hs.demo`

Comment: "kafka-hs.default to kafka-hs.demo" this worked, looks like the brokers are able to communicate with each other now but i'm not able to access them from another service within the kub-cluster, and also not from outside cluster.

Comment: --override advertised.listeners=INTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://${HOSTNAME}.kafka-hs.demo.svc.cluster.local:9093,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://$(eval grep . /var/lib/kafka/external | tail -1) \ , here i am expecting my broker to listen internally using hs service, and external communication to happen on kafka-es service IP which is being read from a file.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to do. Like I said, I don't know what that `grep` command does since the content of that file isn't something native to Kafka, and `echo "service1ip:9092" >> /var/lib/kafka/external` is clearly not going to be correct since service IP addresses in your cluster can change... Still unclear what you have against Strimzi

Comment: I have considered your suggestion and start looking into strimzi, and probably will be using it in prod. but I also wanted to understand what was wrong with my config. please check my updated question

Comment: The advertised listeners get returned to the client, no matter what address you try to connect on. Unless you edit your /etc/hosts or DNS entries, `kafka-service` will return `unknown host` errors. Similarly, the port used in the advertised listeners gets returned as well, so will completely disregard 30001 after the initial bootstrap request. You can use `kcat -L` command to test your listeners

Comment: meaning I should provide something in advertised listener which should be reachable to the client. and internal listener should be something which can be reachable internally within k8 cluster? from other brokers right?

Comment: Right. Your internal listeners seem fine, based on k8s service DNS documentation. Trying to use DNS external to the cluster is more complicated

Comment: thank you for your help, I was able to get a kafka cluster working using strimzi.